# Higher order factorials.

Tags: functions, factorial, gamma-function

The function $y=x!$ can be drawn using the gamma functions, what could function would give higher order factorials like $y=x!!$ where $x!! = x\cdot(x-2)\cdot(x-4)\cdot\ldots\cdot5\cdot3\cdot1$. I have this:
$$\prod\limits_{n=0}^{\lfloor x/k\rfloor-1}(x-kn)$$
Where k is the amount of !'s but obviously this is only valid for integer k, but I'm looking for something which would make would make sense and be continuous for non-integers.

Comment: By the way if anyone could help me with tags  and fixing that floor function in the product that would be great I wasn't sure about this one!

Comment: Would probably look better if you simply wrote $x/k$ instead of $\frac xk$

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Generalizations) suggests $k^{(z-(1-cos(\pi z))/2)/k} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{z}{k}+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k}+1\right)^{\left(1-cos(\pi z)\right)/2}}$ as an extension of the case where $z$ is one more than a multiple of $k$, giving meaningful results for most real and complex $z$ and for positive real $k$

Comment: $x!!=(x!)!$ so why can you not treat this as a composite function ff(x)

Comment: @HenryLee $x!! \neq (x!)!$, $x! = x*(x-1)*(x-2)*...*3*2*1$ where $x!!$ is shown in the question, see [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+(5!)!+%3D+5!!) if you trust wolfram or the wikipedia article in Henry's comment

Comment: This formula holds for $k\in\mathbb{N}$: $(2k)!! = 2^k k!$. The analytic continuation of the factorial is the Gamma function, so it should work with this defintion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the odd case you could take

$$\Gamma_2(z) := 2^{(z-1)/2} \int_0^{\infty} t^{(z-1) /2} e^{-t} dt $$

For $z=1$ you have 1, and différentiation by parts you get

$$ \Gamma_2(z) = 2^{(z-1) /2} \frac{z-1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} t^{(z-3) /2} e^{-t}dt = (z-1) \Gamma_2(z-2) $$

So that by induction you get the right thing. In the even case you just get the semifactorial with a constant in front coming front $z=2$, i.e $\Gamma(1/2) $ which i think is something related to $\pi$ (maybe $\pi/4$). You can go around this problem by multiplying by an oscillating function :

$$ \left ( 1+ \cos( \pi z/2)^2  \alpha \right ) 2^{(z-1) /2} \Gamma((z-1) /2) $$

Where $ \alpha = \Gamma(1/2) -1$